# How can you get the system default language/locale, in a py2app packaged Python app on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, localization

I wrote a simple wxPython app which I package with py2app, turning it into a self-contained double-clickable .app bundle which I can give to other people to run.

My app uses some locale-specific settings -- specifically, it wants to parse dates in text form -- so it lets the user specify what locale to use, and it calls locale.getdefaultlocale() to prepopulate this choice.

I tested this by running the python code directly (in the system-installed Python, not packaged) and it worked fine, then I packaged it with py2app and tested the resulting self-contained app with "open dist/foo.app" and it worked fine.  Then I gave it to somebody else and they complained it immediately threw an exception; I tried double-clicking my .app in the Finder and lo and behold, locale.getdefaultlocale() is indeed returning None (the exception resulted from me making method calls on that object).

I wrote a simple test app that dumps the environment and the value of locale.getdefaultlocale(), and ran it in the same 3 environments. Results:
- invoke directly from Terminal as "python envdump.py": dumps my full environment
- package with py2app, invoke from Terminal as "open dist/envdump.app": dumps my full environment
- invoke that same dist/envdump.app by opening it from Finder: environment is much more limited, and yes, locale.getdefaultlocale() returns (None, None), because LANG is unset.

The complete list of environment variables set by the Finder is: ARGVZERO, Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render, COMMAND_MODE, DISPLAY, EXECUTABLEPAT, HOME, LOGNAME, PATH, PYTHONPATH, RESOURCEPATH, SHELL, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, TMPDIR,USER,__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING.

I can easily make my code tolerate the lack of LANG/locale.getdefaultlocale(), but I'd like to get that information somehow.

Comment: Maybe there is no system default -- apparently the fact that LANG is set in my Terminal windows is specific Terminal.app behavior I didn't know about (which defaults this way, but can be changed).  See http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=93754.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for environment variables for applications launched (by double-clicking, say) are not the same as when run under a terminal window shell.  There is a way to specify those by creating `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`: see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1067.html) for more details.  But that's probably not what you want to do.  If you need to create a default for your app, you can add it to the app's plist as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html).

Comment: Thanks. That first link is indeed not what I want to do, but quite interesting to know that that mechanism is available.

Comment: The point is there is no default `LANG` in the sense of `locale` in OS X.  If you want to get at the user's preferred language(s), you'll need to use the standard Apple interfaces as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html  And that probably means either some C code or using PyObjC.

Comment: Got it. With your additional comment, that completely answers my question, and now I understand the situation. I should have realized that the UI-level stuff in OS X doesn't relate to LANG and that it would actually involve Core Foundation.  I got thrown off by Terminal defaulting to setting LANG for me by default, and thought that was systemwide behavior when it's really just Terminal.app.