# How to set default locale for app bundles in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: python, locale, osx-mountain-lion, nsbundle, py2app

How can I set the default locale (LANG, LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8) with which apps are run in OS X Mountain Lion?

I am trying to run a Python program packaged to an .app with py2app. When running the app by double clicking on it the, code segment

```
import locale
print locale.getlocale()
```

returns (None,None)

However, when running the app from terminal by executing

```
opensesame.app/Contents/MacOS/opensesame
```

the getlocale() function correctly returns (en_US,UTF-8)
 
(As the terminal has the correct environment settings)

I got as far as finding out that apps run in a different environment when double-clicked than when they are run from the terminal, so now I'm trying to set the default encoding variables for apps.

I have tried the suggestions I found on:
[How can you get the system default language/locale, in a py2app packaged Python app on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719789/how-can-you-get-the-system-default-language-locale-in-a-py2app-packaged-python)
and followed the instructions on: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html

I have added both *CFBundleLocalizations* and *LSEnvironment* keys to Info.plist (posted below) inside the app bundle, but the getlocale() function keeps returing (None,None)

Can anyone tell me to correctly set these variables for OS X apps so that Python picks these up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>opensesame</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>opensesame</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>opensesame.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.pythonmac.unspecified.opensesame</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>opensesame</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright not specified</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>LSEnvironment</key>
    <dict>
        <key>LANG</key>
        <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
        <key>LC_ALL</key>
        <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
    </dict>
    <key>PyMainFileNames</key>
    <array>
        <string>__boot__</string>
    </array>
    <key>PyOptions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>alias</key>
        <false/>
        <key>argv_emulation</key>
        <false/>
        <key>emulate_shell_environment</key>
        <false/>
        <key>no_chdir</key>
        <false/>
        <key>prefer_ppc</key>
        <false/>
        <key>site_packages</key>
        <false/>
        <key>use_pythonpath</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>PyResourcePackages</key>
    <array/>
    <key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
    <array>
        <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
    </array>
    <key>PythonInfoDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PythonExecutable</key>
        <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
        <key>PythonLongVersion</key>
        <string>2.7.3 (default, Mar 19 2013, 18:26:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.27)]</string>
        <key>PythonShortVersion</key>
        <string>2.7</string>
        <key>py2app</key>
        <dict>
            <key>alias</key>
            <false/>
            <key>template</key>
            <string>app</string>
            <key>version</key>
            <string>0.7.3</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Which version of py2app do you use? Do other environment variables in LSEnvironment end up in os.environ?  Recent versions of py2app overwrite LC_ALL in the environment to ensure py3k initializes correctly and IIRC I don't restore a previous value of LC_ALL afterwards.

Comment: I've used version 0.7.3, which I believe to be the latest.

Answer (score 0):

With the tip of the 0.7 branch of py2app (which will be 0.7.4 sometime soon) I can partially reproduce the problem, in that locale.getlocale() returns (None, None) regardless of which LC_* variables are set in the environment.

When I call locale.setlocale(locale.LC_AL, "") before calling locale.getlocale() I do get the locale information that's indicated by the LC_ALL or LANG environment variable (set through an LSEnvironment key in the Info.plist when double-clicking on the app).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! However, calling
`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"")`
gives me the error
**Error: unsupported locale setting**

Comment: That's odd. What locale related variables are present in the environment?

Comment: For what it's worth, on my machine (OSX 10.8) I always get LC_CTYPE in the environment, with value  en_US.UTF-8. This is the value used by py2app when bootstrapping the app, for some reason resetting doesn't work.

Comment: Note: I'm tracking the problem in py2app's issue tracker at <https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issue/109/setting-environment-variables>

Comment: Thx Ron for your efforts. I didn't get arount to trying the LC_CTYPE solution, but I will do so asap.